# using SNPs to identify mixed samples

Tags: snp, genotyping

Is there a way to identify mixed samples based on SNPs?

Example input (table of genotypes for multiple samples):

```
|      | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 |
|------|---------|---------|---------|
| rs1  | AA      | BB      | AB      |
| rs2  | AA      | BB      | AB      |
| rs3  | AA      | BB      | AB      |
| rs4  | AA      | BB      | AB      |
```

Desired output: Sample relationships/distances. In this example, sample1 and sample2 are distinct, but sample3 is likely a mix of two (biological or technical).

Based on this simple example, the calculation seems doable, but maybe it's impossible in more complex realistic scenarios.

There is a nice tool [peddy](https://github.com/brentp/peddy) that does something conceptually similar, but it expects pedigree information as well as genotype frequencies for both the input samples and population.

Comment: I updated the question. I didn't initially realize it was not clear.

Comment: Thanks, but this still remains a question that is mostly without context. What is the specific problem that you are trying to solve?

As presented here, those samples could be individuals and the problem is a phasing problem, rather than mixed groups. What platform is being used to carry out the genotyping? How far away from each other are the variants?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The general term for identifying subsets from a mixed group is [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution).

This is easier to do when there is haplotype-level information available (e.g. sequenced reads that span multiple SNPs), but it is possible to get some indication of sample mixes from unlinked SNPs alone.

Deconvolution is helped a lot by having proportional data in the input (e.g. frequencies of genotypes, rather than a single genotype). Most SNPchip platforms have multiple probes per variant, and can provide some indication of variant proportion when digging down into the raw data. Deconvolution is also a lot easier with some knowledge about the component mixes. It's much easier to simulate mixes than to guess at possible mixes.

[Here's a paper](https://investigativegenetics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13323-014-0018-3) about the application of deconvolution in forensics.

[Here's a paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.3337) about a program called CIBERSORT which carries out a deconvolution of immune populations based on gene counts:

Here's another [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3874291/) which discusses the idea in more general terms.

You might find more information on one of these Biostars posts:

- [Deconvolution Methods on RNA-Seq Data](https://www.biostars.org/p/160961/)
- [Differential gene expession analysis in cell populations of mixed tumor and normal cells](https://www.biostars.org/p/121286/)

Comment: I am familiar with the expression-based deconvolution, but that's a different problem. And you can have the same mix of cell populations regardless of how many individuals are mixed in a single library. Do you have any suggestions for SNP-based deconvolution?

Comment: Could you please clarify this in your question. It's not clear how much research you've done on this already, and whether or not you have haplotype-level information available.